# What vector image formats work in MS Word on Mac and Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, microsoft-word, vector-graphics

I'd like to insert a vector image into a MS Word document and have it easily viewable on Mac and Windows. On Word for Mac you can easily insert a PDF, but on Windows you [have to have Acrobat installed](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-pdf-to-your-office-file-74819342-8f00-4ab4-bcbe-0f3df15ab0dc) and it's super-janky.

On Windows you can insert an EMF, but on Mac it only shows an *extremely* low resolution preview of it.

Is there a format that works properly in both versions of Word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using
[Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

You need a recent version of Office -
Microsoft Word added
[support for the SVG vector image format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-office-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c)
in 2017 for Office 365 ProPlus subscribers and this functionality was also included
in the Office 2019 release.